# V Testing gets stuck after starting server

Tags: testing, background-process, vlang

The computer I'm using is:

```
Distributor ID: Pop
Description: Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS
Release: 22.04
Codename: jammy
```

When I start up the server in tests it gets stuck with this banner:

```
---- Testing... ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

[I'm trying to copy how this test is done in V for my own application.](https://github.com/vlang/v/blob/c339ea2ce2b6066354b2f4a495d2ae472055a4e0/vlib/vweb/tests/controller_test.v#L26)

So, an example application is:

In the file `main.v`.

```
module main

import vweb

struct App {
    vweb.Context
}

fn main() {
    mut app := &App{}
    vweb.run(app, 8000)
}

['/hi'; get]
fn (mut app App) get_greeting() vweb.Result {
    return app.text('Hello, George!')
}
```

And the test code is `app_test.v`:

```
module main

import os
import time

const (
    vexe = @VEXE
    serverexe = os.join_path(os.cache_dir(), 'server_tester.exe')
)

fn testsuite_begin() {
    if os.exists(serverexe) {
        os.rm(serverexe) or {}
    }
}

fn test_created_executable() {
    did_server_compile :=
        os.system('${os.quoted_path(vexe)} -o ${os.quoted_path(serverexe)} .')
    assert did_server_compile == 0
    assert os.exists(serverexe)
}

fn test_starts_server() {
    command := '${os.quoted_path(serverexe)} > /dev/null &'
    res := os.system(command) // ######## Test gets stuck here ########
    assert res == 0
    time.sleep(100 * time.millisecond)
}

fn test_fail() {
    assert 4 == 5
}
```

I'm expecting that the `test_fail` function should be reached and fail. But it is never reached.

When I run the code `~/.cache/server_tester.exe > /dev/null &` that is run in the test it properly starts in the background. So, I'm not sure why it isn't starting properly in the background in the code.

[The real life code that I'm writing where the test gets stuck.](https://github.com/jon49/SimpleServer/blob/1fab2af3689399b5414df7db40fec12126f69c59/src/app_test.v#L48)